# SendInput Ctrl + C and then retrieve copied content through Clipboard.GetText doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, sendinput

I have a simple windows forms application with a `TextBox` and a `Button`. Clicking on the `Button` will put focus on the `TextBox` and simulate keystrokes `Ctrl + C` to copy the content into the clipboard. I am doing this key simulation with `SendInput`, also tried `SendKeys.Send("^c")`. This works properly for the copy operation, as I can verify by pasting the content to a notepad or something else.

I then want to programmatically retrieve this copied value through `Clipboard.GetText`. However, the problem is that this method always seems to return the **previous** value in Clipboard instead of the current one. For example, if the sequence of values for my `TextBox` is: "hello", "world", then the sequence of output is: junk, "hello". Below is my code using the `SendKeys` method for simplicity:

```
... highlight TextBox value...

SendKeys.Send("^c");
Thread.Sleep(100);

Console.WriteLine(Clipboard.GetText());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like the message loop needs to be executed before the text is placed in the clipboard

try using

```
  Application.DoEvents();
```

instead of the delay

Answer (score 1):

```
 SendKeys.SendWait("^c");
 Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textBox1.Focus();
Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
textBox2.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
```

Comment: You can also use `textBox1.Copy;` and `textBox2.Paste;` instead of the `Clipboard.SetText()` and `Clipboard.GetText()`

Comment: Sure but it will only work if the text is selected, otherwise it will keep the previous content of the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have not tried these methods but I think they will work. For the purpose of my application and the original question, however, I need to simulate the Ctrl + C keyboard events, and looks like doing `Application.DoEvents` as somebody suggested below is the trick.